# Copying Integer Value From Char Pointer to Local Variable in C

Tags: c, pointers, copy, message-queue

I have a string which I break up into pieces using `strtok`

```
    d.dtype = strtok(incoming.mtext, "|");
    d.threshold= strtok(NULL, "|");
    d.pid = strtok(NULL, "|");
```

Using

```
    printf("device type %s\n", d.dtype);
    printf("device threshold %s\n", d.threshold);
    printf("device pid %s\n", d.pid);
```

I can see everything was assigned correctly.

I'm then sending an outgoing message, my message structure is

```
struct msg_st {
    long int mtype;
    char mtext[BUFSIZ];
};

struct msg_st outgoing;
```

How can I copy the `d.pid` value to my `outgoing.mtype` ?

Comment: `outgoing.mtype = strtol(d.pid, NULL, 10);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract `int` value from `char *` by using [atoi](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/) from `<stdlib.h>`

```
outgoing.mtype = atoi(d.pid);
```

Comment: I could of sworn I tried that and it gave me an error, although it seems to have worked, thanks.

Comment: Glad to know. Don't forget to click the Accept Answer button. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To convert a string value to long int, you can use

```
outgoing.mtype = atol(d.pid);
```